# URL with Moodle

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, moodle

Moodle Version : 3.1
PHP Version  : 5.6

I'm using Symfony2, 
 I have installed moodle in my site already online,
Everything works fine except that when accessing moodle : 
It does not directly access the index.php file of moodle, and when I put index.php manually it works.

And when I put the login and the password, the connection is done but it also does not access the file index.php **http://www.info2000.tn/moodle/my/**    and return the exception :

**No route found for "GET /moodle/my/" (from "http://www.info2000.tn/moodle/login/index.php")around404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpExceptionaround1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »**

But when I delete the .htaccess file that contains the following code :

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [QSA,L]

The moodle works fine but I have a problem with the rest of the site:
I can not directly access www.mywebsite.com
But by adding the web / app.php

Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly you have a Symfony based Site and moodle on the same domain. Is that right?

In that case, you might want to consider using subdomains and use multiple rewrite rules for Symfony and Moodle. Refer https://serverfault.com/questions/577306/redirect-multiple-domains-to-subfolders-and-hide-the-subfolder-from-url

Hope that helped.